# What are these numbers in green color represent when testing react component and running test coverage?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am writing Unit test cases for react components and after successfully implementing the test case. I run code coverage for that particular file.

There is one thing that I noticed which is the numbers written in green color before the statements and branches. I am providing the snapshot of it. So I want to know what this represent.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They represent how many times that line or piece of code was executed. In react testing this number could easily be higher than 1x because of all renders.

Comment: Thanks for such quick reply.

Comment: Can you also tell the difference between
1). Statement
2). Lines

Comment: You can see a list of statements [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements). Basically a statement can have multiple lines like when you define a normal function with a console.log inside. It will be just 1 statement but multiple lines